# Wrong order of arrays in JSON-decoded Object stored with SwiftData

Tags: ios, json, swift, swiftui, swift-data

I'm building a vocabulary app. On first launch, the JSON is decoded and the resulting objects are saved using SwiftData. The JSON is structured in layered Arrays (Array of Units that have each have an array of lessons that each have an array of vocabulary). The units are in the right order because I order them via @Query by their id. But the lessons and vocabulary objects are in the wrong order. Why does this occur?

```
func load<T: Decodable>(_  filename: String) -> T {
    let data: Data    
    guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)
    else {
        fatalError("Couldn't find \(filename) in main bundle!")
    }
    
    do {
        data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't load \(filename) from main bundle:\n\(error)")
    }
    
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't parse \(filename) as \(T.self):\n\(error)")
    }
}
```

JSON load function

```
import Foundation
import SwiftData

@Model
final class Unit: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: Int
    var lessons: [Lesson]
    
    init(id: Int, lessons: [Lesson]) {
        self.id = id
        self.lessons = lessons
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        lessons = try container.decode([Lesson].self, forKey: .lessons)
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(id.self, forKey: .id)
        try container.encode(lessons.self, forKey: .lessons)
    }
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, lessons
    }
    
    
}

@Model
final class Lesson: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: Int
    var vocab: [Vocab]
    
    init(id: Int, vocab: [Vocab]) {
        self.id = id
        self.vocab = vocab
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        vocab = try container.decode([Vocab].self, forKey: .vocab)
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(id.self, forKey: .id)
        try container.encode(vocab.self, forKey: .vocab)
    }
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, vocab
    }
}

@Model
final class Vocab: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: Int
    var word: String
    var meaning: String
    var url: String
    var practiceData: PracticeData
    
    init(id: Int, word: String, meaning: String, url: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.word = word
        self.meaning = meaning
        self.url = url
        self.practiceData = PracticeData()
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        self.word = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .word)
        self.meaning = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .meaning)
        self.url = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .url)
        self.practiceData = PracticeData()
    }
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, word, meaning, url, practiceData
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(id.self, forKey: .id)
        try container.encode(word.self, forKey: .word)
        try container.encode(meaning.self, forKey: .meaning)
        try container.encode(url.self, forKey: .url)
        try container.encode(practiceData.self, forKey: .practiceData)
    }
}
```

Decoded Objects

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "lessons": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "vocab": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "word": xxx,
            "meaning": xxx,
            "url": xxx
          },
          ...
        ]
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

JSON structure

```
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query(sort: \Unit.id) private var units: [Unit]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(units) { unit in
                    Text(String(unit.id))
                    UnitRow(unit: unit)
                }
            }
        }
        ...
    }
```

View

[image: (number in circle is lesson.id)]

number in circle is lesson.id

Comment: While you have arrays in your models and in your JSON, under the covers SwiftData is Core Data.  Core Data is going to store these arrays as a `Set` of relationships to the related entities (So `unit.lessons` is a set of `Lesson` relationships).  This set of relationships is unordered.  You will need to explicitly query for the lessons and order by their `id`.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. How do I query for the Lessons of only 1 unit?

Comment: You can sort the lessons in the UnitRow view as well.

Comment: How do I do that? I wasn’t able to find out by googling. Best case would be if I could sort all of them (so units, lessons and vocab by Id)

Comment: `lessons` is an array so you can use [sorted(by:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/sorted(by:)) for instance